# Unable format JSON date object

Tags: jquery, date, json

I am not able to format the date object received by JSON. The object looks like this

```
{
    "date": 2,
    "day": 1,
    "hours": 0,
    "minutes": 0,    
    "month": 2,
    "nanos": 0,
    "seconds": 0,
    "time": 1425234600000,
    "timezoneOffset": -330,
    "year": 115
}
```

Tried [How to format JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363263/how-to-format-json-date) and many other ways but no luck!!!

I want to format the date in **yyyy-MM-dd**

**EDIT:**

This is how the object in my browser debugger looks like

[image]

Comment: What you have is a UNIX timestamp, not a 'JSON date'

Comment: Oh!! Thanks for educating me! i was unaware of it! can you guide me how to format it?

Comment: No problem - see the question I marked as duplicate

Comment: The debugger says Invalid Date when i tried solving like that!!

Comment: Your timestamp is already in milliseconds, so you can skip the `* 1000` logic

Comment: Still it says invalid date, FYI the one i posted is stringified JSON object!!

Comment: Are you sure? It looks a lot like the object itself. Please add your actual code to the question.

Comment: I still don't see how what you have doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/e6ed92sc/

Comment: Thanks! it is working i stumbled with time!!